# How can I change the locale in html 5 input[datetime-local]?

Tags: html, datepicker

Is there any way to change the locale of a input of type `datetime-locale`? I could not find a configuration for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate question.

[Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

**There is no way to do that in a standard way.**
You're maybe interested in 1st answer and the 2nd most up voted answer.